# Any collection of n coins can be obtained using a combination of 3¢ and 5¢ coins where n ≥ 14

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I am trying to prove this statement **with strong induction**, but I'm a little lost on the inductive step.

**Proposition:** Let P(n) be the sentence ‘any collection of n coins can be obtained using a combination of 3¢ and 5¢ coins.’

P(n) is true for all integers where n ≥ 14.

**Proof:**

**Prove P(14) is true:**

P(14) is true, because 14¢ can be obtained with 3(3¢) and 1(5¢). (9¢ + 5¢ = 14¢)

**Prove P(15) is true:**

P(15) is true, because 15¢ can be obtained with 5(3¢). (15¢ = 15¢)

**Prove P(16) is true:**

P(16) is true, because 16¢ can be obtained with 2(3¢) and 2(5¢). (6¢ + 10¢ = 16¢)

**Show that for all integers n ≥ 14, if P(i) is true for all integers i from 14 through k, then P(k+1) is also true:**

Assume that P(i) is true for all integers from 14 through k.

$k + 1 = [(k + 1) - 3] + 3$

If $k + 1 ≥ 16$, then $(k + 1) - 3 ≥ 14$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Is it essential that you use induction?  It seems easier without.

Comment: This is a special case of the Coin Problem a.k.a. the Chicken McNugget Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem .

Comment: I think your almost done. If k is bigger than 15 then k+1-3 is bigger than 13, so by hypothises can be obtained by a combination of 3 and 5 cent pieces. Now you just add a 3 cent piece...

Comment: It's even true for $n\ge 8$ (8=5+3, 9=3+3+3, 10=5+5), then add 3 as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove it with strong induction you have to assume $n>14$ and that the result is true for every $k$ with $14\le k<n$, after having verified the case $n=14$.

If $n=15$, or $n=16$, you've already done the computations. If $n>16$, then $n-3>13$, so $n-3=3a+5b$ by the (strong) induction hypothesis. Therefore $n=3(a+1)+5b$.